# Semester Break in Germany during PhD

Tags: phd, thesis, germany, thesis-committee

I wanted to apply for an official semester break during my PhD; I am enrolled in a German University; my concern is that could I show the paper published during the semester break in the dissertation?

Comment: What does it mean to "apply for a semester break"? Every semester ends just like every week does, without any need for an application.

Comment: @henning I assume this is an odd translation of "Freisemester", which basically means suspending ones studies for a term. It is a bit unclear to me though what the point of doing this as a PhD student would be.

Answer (score 6):

I assume with "semester break" you mean taking a *Freisemester*, although it is unclear to me what the point of that as a PhD student would be. The general idea of a *Freisemester* is that the student is busy with something other than their studies; and they'll usually not be able to progress via e.g. sitting exams.

To figure out how your university handles *Freisemester*, and what is and what is not possible during them, you will need to consult the *Prüfungsordnung*, and in your case, also the *Promotionsordnung*. After you have done that, discuss the idea with your PhD supervisor and query them regarding whatever is unclear in the official rules.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that should be a worry, though I'm not from Germany. Doctoral students do a lot of productive things when they aren't "on the clock".

And, how would they know, unless you make an issue of it? It is pretty likely that you worked on the paper during "official time" anyway.

But you might also have a quiet word with your supervisor. "Hey, I had a weird thought..."

Comment: okay, thanks for your suggestion, glad that you replied to it.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, doing a PhD is detached from being enrolled as a student in Germany.

More recently, it has become customary to be enrolled as a PhD student and/or be part of a graduate school for a certain minimal amount of time (e.g. 2 years). Nevertheless, it does not mean you cannot use results obtained outside that time for your PhD.

So there shouldn't be a problem, **unless** there is a requirement that you have to be enrolled or part of the graduate school for a certain consecutive period of time. But, again, this will not be a problem for the material you include in your thesis.